# Android: detect screen orientation change also if orientation is lock

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

I have an Android app with one Activity and a custom ViewPager with several fragments. My entire activity is locked in portrait, but now i need to detect, inside a specific fragment, when device is in landscape and launch another activity locked in landscape. In this new activity, when user put device in portrait, i would close it and return to portrait activity. 
This is AndroidManifest.xml code:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.mypackage.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
    </activity>
```

and this is code inside fragment that should detect landscape:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration myConfig) {
    int orient = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    switch (orient) {
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
        //Launch new activity
        break;
    }       
}
```

Now i've noticed that onConfigurationChanges is never called with this manifest configuration, but is called only if i remove

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

There's a way to keep MainActivity locked in portrait and intercept landscape too?

Answer (score -1):

> Now i've noticed that onConfigurationChanges() is never called

why this is so surpring to you? You explicitely disabled orientation change so there's no point of this method to be called. Note that orientation refers to **screen** orientation, not orientation of the device.

> when device is in landscape and launch another activity locked in landscape

You either eat cake or keep cake so you either enforce fixed orientation or have `onConfigurationChanges()` called.

> launch another activity locked

why not simply have separate layout file for the same activity? Switch will be automatically handled by the framework, so no special code is needed - just file in properly named folder (see docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: because i have a ViewPager inside my activity designed for work only in portrait,  and because i need to switch in portrait only if user is on a specific fragment

Comment: then it seems you got something incorrectly designed in terms that such ViewPager should be used only in portrait. But it should not need to be aware of the orientation as it should not be its task